# Indirect parameter expansion in associative array

Tags: bash, parameter, associative-array

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1921337/6005145), I want to apply the approach on my script. The basics of it is:

```
foo="bar" 
baz="foo"
echo "${!baz}"
bar
```

I want to provide translated strings, like this:

```
declare -A es
declare -A en

#
es["greet"]="Hola"
en["greet"]="Hello"
#
es["world"]="Mundo"
en["world"]="World"
```

Then at the top of my script I would set:

```
lang="es"
```

then

```
echo "${!lang["greet"]} ${!lang["world"]}"
```

I would expect the output:

```
Hola Mundo
```

or

```
lang="en"

echo "${!lang["greet"]}" "${!lang["world"]}"

Hello World
```

But all I get are empty strings.

Is it possible to do this or should I explore other ways?

---

So far I've come with two approaches, none of them I like:

```
declare -A hello
hello["es"]="Hola"
hello["en"]="Hello"

declare -A world
world["es"]="Mundo"
world["en"]="World"

lang="es"

echo "${hello[$lang]} ${world[$lang]}"
Hola Mundo
```

The other:

```
lang="es"

if [[ "$lang" = "es" ]]; then
  declare -A language=(
    ["greet"]="Hola"
    ["world"]="Mundo"
  )
elif [[ "$lang" = "en" ]]; then
  declare -A language=(
    ["greet"]="Hello"
    ["world"]="World"
  )
fi

echo "${language["greet"]} ${language["world"]}"
Hola Mundo
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a name-reference variable instead of indirection.

With your initial set-up of the associative arrays `en` and `es`:

```
$ declare -n lang=en
$ echo "${lang["greet"]} ${lang["world"]}"
Hello World
$ declare -n lang=es
$ echo "${lang["greet"]} ${lang["world"]}"
Hola Mundo
```

The value of the `lang` name-reference is the name of another variable.  Accessing the variable `lang` will be the same as accessing that named variable.

Name-reference variables are available in the `bash` shell since release 4.3.